# Finding Two Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that we have $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^k$ such that $||x|| \le 1$ and $||y|| \le 1$. Do there exist unit vectors $u_1$ and $u_2$ in $\mathbb{C}^m$ such that $\langle u_1, u_2 \rangle = \langle x,y \rangle$?

Answer (score 0):

YEs.  The range of the scalar Product on $\mathbb C^n $ is $=\mathbb C $

Comment: Would you mind going into a little more detail?